# Aspose.Words adding paragraphs via DocumentBuilder does not update Document info

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.words

I'm trying to write a extension method for Aspose's `DocumentBuilder` class that allows you to check if inserting a number of paragraphs into a document will cause a page break or not, I hoped this would be rather simple, but it turns out otherwise:

```
public static bool WillPageBreakAfter(this DocumentBuilder builder, int numParagraphs) 
{
    // Get current number of pages
    int pageCountBefore = builder.Document.PageCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < numParagraphs; i++) 
    {
        builder.InsertParagraph();
    }

    // Get the number of pages after adding those paragraphs
    int pageCountAfter = builder.Document.PageCount;

    // Delete the paragraphs, we don't need them anymore
    ...

    if (pageCountBefore != pageCountAfter) 
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else  
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

MY problem is, that inserting paragraphs does not seem to update the `builder.Document.PageCount` property. Even plugging in something crazy like 5000 paragraphs does seem to modify that property. I've also tried `InsertBreak()` (including using `BreakType.PageBreak`) and `Writeln()` but those don't work either.

What's going on here? Is there anyway I can achieve the desired result?

**UPDATE**

It seems that absolutely nothing done on the `DocumentBuilder` parameter actually happens on the `DocumentBuilder` that is calling the method. In other words:

If I modify the for loop to do something like `builder.InsertParagraph(i.ToString());` and then remove the code that deletes the paragraphs afterwords. I can call:

```
myBuilder.WillPageBreakAfter(10);
```

And expect to see 0-9 written to the document when it is saved, however it is not. None of the `Writeln()`s in the extension methods seem to do anything at all.

**UPDATE 2**

It appears for what ever reasons, I cannot write anything with the `DocumentBuilder` after accessing the page count. So calling something like `Writeln()` before the `int pageCountBefore = builder.Document.PageCount;` line works, but trying to write after that line simply does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And it seems I've figured it out.

From the Aspose docs:

> ```
> // This invokes page layout which builds the document in memory so note that with large documents this 
> // property can take time. After invoking this property, any rendering operation e.g rendering to PDF or image 
> // will be instantaneous. 
> int pageCount = doc.PageCount;
> ```

The most important line here:

> This invokes page layout

By "invokes page layout", they mean it calls `UpdatePageLayout()`, for which the docs contain this note:

> However, if you modify the document after rendering and then attempt to render it again - Aspose.Words will not update the page layout automatically. In this case you should call UpdatePageLayout() before rendering again.

So basically, given my original code, I have to call `UpdatePageLayout()` after my `Writeln()`s in order to get the updated page count.

// Get current number of pages
    int pageCountBefore = builder.Document.PageCount;

```
for (int i = 0; i < numParagraphs; i++) 
{
    builder.InsertParagraph();
}
// Update the page layout.
builder.Document.UpdatePageLatout();

// Get the number of pages after adding those paragraphs
int pageCountAfter = builder.Document.PageCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Document.PageCount invokes page layout. You are modifying the document after using this property. Note that when you modify the document after using this property, Aspose.Words will not update the page layout automatically. In this case you should call Document.UpdatePageLayout method.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.